# Bypassing prompt (to press return) in homebrew install script

Tags: bash, homebrew

Very simple script that installs homebrew:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

The output gives:

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
```

How do I press enter in a script like this? Would expect be the best route?

Comment: The first thing to do is to see if you can skip that by redirecting stdin from `/dev/null`: `ruby -e "$(curl ...)" </dev/null`. Well-behaved programs will only prompt from the user if their stdin is connected to a TTY.

Comment: ...meaning that if homebrew aborts in that case, you can file a bug (or submit a patch), because it's *not* well-behaved.

Comment: `ruby -e ... < <(yes '')` is another approach, which will rely on the `yes` program to continually produce affirmatives. Don't do this unless `</dev/null` doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Reading the source of https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install -- it only prompts if stdin is a TTY. If you redirect stdin from `/dev/null`, it won't prompt at all. So:

```
ruby \
  -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" \
  </dev/null
```

Comment: Can i add user password in installation command to avoid user interaction ?

Comment: @FilthyKnight did you able to bypass password anyway? I am also facing the issue.

Comment: How do i combine this with `echo $password | sudo -S ...`?

Comment: @jinbeomhong, just take out the `</dev/null` -- `echo "$password" |` (the quotes are mandatory to make it work correctly with unusual passwords) itself makes stdin no longer be a TTY.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But how to install HomeBrew automatically? Could you write an entire command? I tried `yes '' | echo "$password" | sudo -S /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` too. It didn't work (referenced to other answer..)

Comment: There's no point to `yes '' | echo` -- `echo` doesn't read from stdin at all, so piping to it is useless. And as I said before, when you pipe to `sudo`, that itself means that your copy of bash no longer gets its input from a TTY, so you stop needing `yes` at all.

Comment: @jinbeomhong, ...that said: I don't use homebrew, and I don't recommend that anyone else use it either (as package managers for MacOS go, [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) does much less harm to a system's security posture when installed in multi-user mode); so I'm not in a position to test an answer to any follow-up questions.

Answer (score 26):

This is what [`yes`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/yes.1.php) is for:

```
yes '' | ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Comment: @datasmid There *is* a difference between the two, and my solution works without relying on an undocumented feature - that "it only prompts if stdin is a TTY".

Comment: @l0b0, sure, but if it's not documented that it'll read from stdin rather than reading from a TTY, then we don't have a (documented, ongoing) guarantee that this will work regardless. There's undocumented behavior being relied on all 'round.

Comment: @datasmid `yes` is and always had been documented; it's part of the GNU Core Utilities. That means it's on every POSIX-compliant system since the beginning. The fact that you have not used it doesn't mean it's not real.
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/yes-invocation.html

Comment: @todd_dsm, the claim that GNU coreutils is present on all POSIX systems is entirely false -- many UNIXes (including MacOS, FreeBSD, Solaris/SunOS and frankly *most* of the commercial Unixlikes) use their own utilities rather than GNU implementations. The table of contents for the POSIX "shell and utilities" section is at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html; `yes` is not part of the set.

Comment: @todd_dsm, ...and as for "since the beginning", GNU `yes` (which predates coreutils, having first been written as part of shellutils) was first written in 1991. UNIX had been around a good long time at that point.

Comment: @todd_dsm, ...anyhow, it's not the behavior of `yes` I was saying was undocumented; it was the behavior of `brew install`, in terms of whether it prompts on stdin or from a TTY.

Comment: @charles-duffy "since the beginning" = 1968. Which I can pin-point as my uncle was there.

Comment: @charles-duffy GNU coreutils exists for Linux but keep in mind, Linux is just a kernel; not all the system utilities were invented for it. Some, like some of the GNU tools, were just new ports of old, time-hardened software. A few GNU programs that predate Linux: awk, grep, sed, etc. I should have my GF chime in. She has her name on some pre-version1 POSIX specs.
  The purpose behind the FSF was to avoid some of the licensing issues that UNIX had - not to reinvent the wheels.

Comment: @todd_dsm, I don't disagree with any portion of your immediately-prior comment, but I *do* posit that said comment fails to adequately support your prior, challenged, assertion.

Answer (score 6):

[Per the lead maintainer of Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/46779#issuecomment-162819088):

```
echo | /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Comment: In the paragraph above that, the aforementioned maintainer *also* refers to the TTY check ("checks if it's being run in a terminal with inactivity", a check which`</dev/null` will cause to fail).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: No disagreement that the input redirection of your accepted answer works. That said, I still prefer and use this version because a) it's trivially shorter and b) MikeMcQuaid wrote it.  (Also, I think you want to edit "inactivity" to "interactivity" in your comment).

Comment: Alas, the 5-minute edit window was already long past when the suggestion was made.

Comment: This was the easiest solution to get past the installer getting stuck on `press RETURN`

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me,

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null
```