# ansible module actions without install

Tags: installation, ansible, homebrew

I'm writing an Ansible playbook to configure new machines for our developing environment.

If I want to install `postgresql` using `homebrew`, I would use Ansible's given `homebrew` model to achieve this task.

But before I run this task, should I have a task that will install `homebrew` first?

If this is the case, how can I install `homebrew` using the `command` or `shell` Ansible module, which will normally prompt for a user input during the process of installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bypassing prompt (to press return) in homebrew install script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535407/bypassing-prompt-to-press-return-in-homebrew-install-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to install Homebrew first. The `homebrew` Ansible module documentation is not clear about that; if you check its [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1b727c372e295183c9d53ef52a30751502263c15/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/homebrew.py) it fails if it can’t find Homebrew and it doesn’t try to install it for you.

There already are answers on [how to bypass the prompt in Homebrew’s install script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25535407/735926). There are also other [ways of installing Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Installation.md#alternative-installs) like downloading it as a tarball and un-`tar`ing it somewhere (which you can do with the [`unarchive` Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html)) or cloning its source code using [`git`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html).