# How to send variable containing password to subprocess?

Tags: python, macos

I'm building an app to update git across our environment. When it detects that homebrew is not installed, it runs the homebrew install command. While that is running however, it asks for a password. I tried the following below but getting

Warning: Running in non-interactive mode because `stdin` is not a TTY.
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user christian needs to be an Administrator)!

Any ideas?

```py
def run_upgrade():
    entry_password = entry.text()
    version_cmd = subprocess.run(['git', '--version'], capture_output=True, text=True)
    version = version_cmd.stdout.split()[2]
    if version == "2.40.1":
        msg_box.setText(f"Current Version: {version}  Already up to Date!")
    else:
        homebrew_check = subprocess.run(['command', '-v', 'brew'], capture_output=True, text=True)
        while homebrew_check.stdout == "":
            install = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            install.stdin.write(bytes(entry_password, 'utf-8'))
        else:
            msg_box.setText(f"Latest version installed!")
            subprocess.run(['brew', 'install', 'git'])
```

Also, the way homebrew works - it doesn't allow me to have sudo access before running the script. It returns "Do not run this as root". ‍♂️

Comment: Show output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: It returns blank. When I run bash, it shows bash-3.2$. FYI, I’m on macOS and I believe they stopped updating bash past version 3.2 in favor of zsh.

Comment: That's what it says to do to install homebrew. https://brew.sh
Is that what's causing the issue?

Comment: I had overlooked that you explicitly use `bash` in your code.

Comment: No worries! What do you suppose the issue is?

Comment: Things that take passwords typically don't read them from stdin. A tool like pexpect might be more suitable for this use case.

Comment: Also there might be answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426424/unattended-no-prompt-homebrew-installation-using-expect

Comment: I was so excited but no. That's NONINTERACTIVE in the sense that there's no continue prompt but password prompt exists. They updated the wording on their GitHub but not their public facing site. 

Comment: As was said -- sudo and other common tools prompt for passwords direct from the TTY, not from stdin, to prevent people from following exactly the kind of practice you're doing here; passwords are supposed to be entered interactively by humans to indicate that human's explicit consent. You shouldn't be trying to enter a password from a script in the first place -- if the system administrator wants to allow a specific operation to be performed automatically, `/etc/sudoers` should say so, so sudo doesn't ask for a password at all when that operation is attempted.

Comment: That said, you can start as root and then drop to an unprivileged user for only the specific parts of your script that homebrew doesn't let you be privileged for. But my preference would be to completely excise homebrew and use a different set of tools (macports, nix, etc) altogether; homebrew's security model ("we don't want the user using sudo all the time, so we're going to make executables writable by an unprivileged user with no explicit escalation at all") is one of the worst ideas I've ever seen. It's only marginally better than systems where root is the only user account there is.

Comment: Is this a terminal or GUI app?